# PowerShell falling short on performance when wildcard used multiple times for deleting files matching specific filename patterns

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, command-history

As I mentioned in Q-title, I have put together fairly well-built function for clearing history completely (not keeping any ugly junks or leftovers).

But it seems that due to multiple occurrences of wildcard character (`*`) it doesn't perform at all and the history file is still there.

This is the code that I put together (it is added in `$profile` file so can be accessed from anywhere in the system) which is fairly straightforward and definitely expected to work, as Powershell developers has made the commands to be mostly similar and complying with the Bash/Batch script counterparts:

```
if (Get-Command -Verb Invoke -Noun Remove-Alias) {
    Remove-Alias history
} else {
    If (Test-Path Alias:history) {Remove-Item Alias:history}
    If (Test-Path Alias:history) {Remove-Item Alias:history}
}

function history {
    param (
        # Clears history
        [Parameter()]
        [Alias("c")]
        [Switch]
        $Clear
    )

    if ($Clear){
        Clear-History
        [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::ClearHistory()
        rm -fo -r $ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\*history*
        del -fo -r $ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\*history*
        return
    }

    Get-History
}
```

But when I use this `Alias` thro' `history -c` from anywhere, its not deleting the `ConsoleHost_history.txt` present at `$ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine`, which is really undesired and unexpected, can anyone help achieve this with pointing out what is put wrong (is it due to non-acceptance of multiple asterisks as wildcards unlike bash?) and with minimal change suggestions?

**Note:** Windows 10 64Bit and Powershell >= 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's because PowerShell's `rm` interprets wildcards much *like* bash does – non-recursively. If you tried to do the same in bash, you'd notice that `PowerShell/*history*` only matches `PowerShell/Command_history.txt` but never `PowerShell/PSReadLine/Command_history.txt`, and you would need `**` (bash's "globstar" option) for the latter.

Only PowerShell's `dir` is a special case here, and it would look for `*history*` even in subdirectories of the provided path as if you had provided the wildcard through `-Filter` (the result is similar to how it works in Cmd.exe). For example, these do the same thing but *only* with `dir`:

```
dir -r $ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell -filter *history*
dir -r $ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\*history*
```

Many cmdlets implicitly work on the "input objects" if no arguments are given, so you can directly pipe PowerShell's `dir` into `rm`:

```
dir -r $ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\*history* | rm -whatif
```

---

Of course, it would be simpler to just include the `PSReadLine` subdirectory in the wildcard, since it's always going to be part of the path anyways:

```
rm $ENV:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadLine\*history*
```

Comment: Guess I had misplaced expectations, thank you for informative answer..